# react querying from firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im building a webapp using react . i succesfully uploaded user data from a webpage. while querying im getting an error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:

> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
mport { collection, orderBy, onSnapshot, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import Post from "./Post";

function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(
        query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc")),
        (snapshot) => {
          setPosts(snapshot.docs);
        }
      ),
    [db]
  );
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          key={post.id}
          id={post.id}
          username={post.data().username}
          img={post.data().img}
          caption={post.data().caption}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

    export default Posts;
```

Comment: What is in Post? React does not render undefined values as children.

Comment: post renders the page from the data from {key={post.id}
          id={post.id}
          username={post.data().username}
          img={post.data().img}
          caption={post.data().caption}}